# count cells without an array - locate cell without using loops??? I dont think i worded this correctly

Tags: java

I have some code for a vampire project / game...and i want to know if there is an easy way to make an if statement to check if a certain object "H" which stands for hunter...which surrounded by eight possible cells...if another object "V" which stands for vampire is in any of this eight cells the program will check so, and if so will print out a result that the hunter has slain the vampire...if anyone knows an easy way to do this please let me know you can...Bijan

I have come up with this algorithm yet it doesnt work :

```
if((vampire.getI() & vampire.getJ()) - (hunter.getI() & hunter.getJ()) == (vampire.getI()&vampire.getJ())){
```

getI / getJ are coordinates that the user enters for vampire and hunter...then after the first iteration,  the hunter randomly moves anywhere from 1 cell to 4 cells in any random direction...i just want to make an algorithm to do :

if the hunter "H" is adjacent (horizontal, vertical, diagonally) to any "V",  the vampire is dead...now also if the V is directly on the H,  then the hunter turns into a vampire,  i have come up with this algorithm for hunter to vampire

:

```
if(vampire.getI() == hunter.getI() && vampire.getJ() == hunter.getJ())
```

I also want to know one more thing...
`If "V" enters hunter space...then output will be vampire bites hunter`...
`if hunter moves into "V space,  then hunter causes V to become slain`...
if anyone knows please let me know if you can,  Bijan

Comment: Why can't you loop? It can do it relatively fast..

Comment: There is no way to do this without arrays, or something that simulates or wraps arrays.  This question makes little sense to me.  *"I dont think i worded this correctly"* - probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

Me personally I'd prefer loops, there is a nice trick to do that, something like:

```
int[] DY = { -1, -1, -1,  0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1 };
int[] DX = { -1,  0,  1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1 };
```

and then using loop to check

```
for ( int i = 0; i < di.length; ++i)
    if (V.getX() == H.getX() + DX[i] && V.getY() == H.getY() + DY[i]) {
        // on same position, do something and end loop
        break;
    }
```

I'm suggesting to also refactor `getI`/`getJ` to `getX`/`getY`.

Even if the above code is easy to write and I'd recommend to use it, becuase when you will be working in bigger team, it is important that others understand your code easily...

...but, you wanted something else...

Check for 4 neighboring cells is easy

```
int dx = Math.abs( V.getX() - H.getX() );
int dy = Math.abs( V.getY() - H.getY() );
if (dx + dy = 1) {
    // neighbors
}
```

for 8 is a little bit more difficult, but not so much

```
int dx = Math.abs( V.getX() - H.getX() );
int dy = Math.abs( V.getY() - H.getY() );
if (dx <=1 && dy <= 1) {
    // neighbors
}
```

Comment: hey thanks alot it works...you figured that out very easily...i just dont understand how the code works 100% but i will try to figure it out...i already implemented into the code I was doing and adjusted some things like V to vampire H to hunter and i made getX = getI and getY = getJ like the program has it declared but thank you so much for your help...Bijan